# CoordinatorLayout with NestedScrollView behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am a Android newbie programmer and I am stuck with a UI problem. My goal is to achieve something closer to this:
[desirable layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohTPD.png)

I thought about it and I decided to do it with a CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout / CollapsingToolbarLayout and a NestedScrollView with a CardView. Sounds just fine for this problem, right?

With my actual XML I already have the toolbar, image and the scroll feature.

However, the scroll feature isn't 100% like I wanted. First of all, it's not possible to scroll down since around mid screen (probably because of `android:layout_height="275dp"`), it is only possible to scroll up. (and of course collapse the toolbar). My main goal is to "open" the image fullscreen. Do you have any idea how can I achieve this behaviour? Maybe controlling % in .java?

Also have one annoying bug, but I can leave with it for now, just try to help if it also gives you some OCD condition

I tried to add an transparent property to my `LinearLayout` but it didn't work.

Normal scroll:
[Current scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol0dk.png)

Buggy 'panel' as it is close to collapse:
[buggy panel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mis11.png)

My all XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/annonce.main.coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/flexible.example.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/flexible_example_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="275dp"
            app:title="Mosteiro dos Jerónimos"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="94dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingTextAppearance.Inverse"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/mosteiro_dos_jeronimos"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/flexible.example.toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@null"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:title="Mosteiro dos Jerónimos"
                style="@style/ToolBarWithNavigationBack"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="78dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/flexible.example.cardview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentPaddingBottom="16dp"
                app:contentPaddingLeft="16dp"
                app:contentPaddingRight="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                app:cardElevation="4dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/myRectangleView"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Lisboa"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Header"
                        style="@style/TextComponent.ItemRow"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:text="@string/lorem"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/flexible.example.fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_adb_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/flexible.example.cardview"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your layout is fine (works on my side), but maybe the behavior you want is more something like a Bottomsheet behavior.

[Have you had a look at it?](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior)

Basically this will make you able something like google maps, so you would be able to scroll like you want.

[Here is a tutorial to have a better understanding of what it is like.](https://www.androidauthority.com/bottom-sheets-707252/)

Please let me know if this is what you're looking for.